Probelmas al genera Enterprise application con maven en netbeans el error Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2
Hola saludos espero me puedan orientar. Estoy teniendo problemas al crear una aplicacion empresarial java con el ide netbeans 12.6.
Ya configure correctamente la versión y variables de entorno de maven y java
Software utilizado:
Netbeans 12.6
JDK 8
Maven 3.9.6
el error que me arroja al intentar crear la aplicacion es:

Alguien más le ha pasado y saber como lo pudo solucionar gracias saludos
